# How do I store value and display in TableView after succesful HTTP request

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using this method to make HTTP request and it successfully return the key and value.

```
let url = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "api.com")!)

let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        do {
            if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
```

There is two keys from the JSON, "title" as String, and "banner" as URL that I need to store as a variable, for displaying in a TableView. How can I store the values? I searched for lots of solution but it doesn't work.

JSON Output

```
"promotion":[  
  {  

     "title":"4G LTE",
     "banner":"imageurl"
  },
```

Comment: Please share your json output.

Comment: @Profstyle updated

Comment: you can create an enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to store it in a `struct`. It could be like the following:

```
struct Promotion {
    let title: String
    let banner: String 

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
        banner = dictionary["banner"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can feed a dictionary to it. I can not what happens after `convertedJsonIntoDict` line, but you can use this `struct` the following:

```
// Create a container for storing the promotions
var promotions: [Promotion] = []
// Iterate through every dictionary
for dictionary in convertedJsonIntoDict {
// Create  a promotion
    let promotion = Promotion(dictionary: dictionary as [String : AnyObject])
    promotions.append(promotion)
} 
// Check what do you have in promotions
print(promotions)
```

Hope this helps!